# elfinder create files/folder with certain permissions?

Tags: elfinder

Is it possible to set elfinder to create upload files/folder with default unix permissions, so for example all uploaded files to be 0777?

There is for example a "front end" permissions option in elfinder, which is from the driver passing a pattern to lock files, or to hide files, but what I am looking for is do it at filesystem level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options `dirMode` and `fileMode` to set permission of new items.

- https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#localfilesystem

```
    array(
        'driver'         => 'LocalFileSystem',
        'path'           => 'PathToTargetDirectory',
        'dirMode'        => 0755,            // new dirs mode (default 0755)
        'fileMode'       => 0644,            // new files mode (default 0644)
        'quarantine'     => '.quarantine',   // quarantine folder name. Absolute path is also possible. (default '.quarantine') - required to check archive (must be hidden)
        'followSymLinks' => true,            // follow symbolic links (default true) (elFinder >= 2.1.8)
        'detectDirIcon'  => '',              // File to be detected as a folder icon image (elFinder >= 2.1.10) e.g. '.favicon.png'
        'keepTimestamp'  => 'array('copy', 'move')', // Keep timestamp at inner filesystem (elFinder >= 2.1.12) It allowed 'copy', 'move' and 'upload'.
    )
```